# How to create an array in jsf tags using Onchange function?

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a generic function for clear the text box and checked the radio button. The following are the code for that function

```
function initData(checkId,data) {
   alert(checkId);
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    alert(data);
    document.getElementById(data).value = "";
   }
   document.getElementById(checkId).checked = true;
   alert('done');
}
```

Now I need to create an array in jsf tags using Onchange function.The following are the code

```
<h:inputText value="#{termPurchaseUIBean.effectiveRate}" styleClass="textInput" id="effectiveRateText" onchange="initData2('termPurchase:selectRate:1',new Array()['termPurchase:effectiveRateText']);" label="#{label.TermPurchase_EffectiveRate}">
```

`

But this code is not working. Can any one of you help me to create an array in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementById()` call inside the loop is incorrect. You want to pass the current array item `data[i]` as ID, not the whole `data` array.

```
document.getElementById(data[i]).value = "";
```

The array creation is incorrect. Remove the `new Array()`. It will already implicitly be done with `[]`.

```
onchange="initData2('termPurchase:selectRate:1', ['termPurchase:effectiveRateText']);"
```

Comment: I have tried that also BalusC. The following code is item = data[i];
   
   document.getElementById(item).value = "";

Comment: In Onchange event the array creation is right or not BalusC.Because in alert am not getting the value of data and am getting the value of checkId in alert

Comment: Very good, that's more helpful information than "it doesn't work"! The way how you created the array is indeed wrong. I updated the answer.